# Docker : Add a valid entrypoint for multiple python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, bash, docker

Helli, I have to build a Docker image for the following bioinformatics tool: https://github.com/CAMI-challenge/CAMISIM. Their dockerfile works but takes a long time to build and I would like to build my own, slightly differently, to learn. I face issues: there are several python script that I should be able to choose to run, not only a `main`. If I add one script in particular as an `ENTRYPOINT` then the behavior isn't exactly what I shoud have.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
USER root
#COPY ./install_docker.sh ./
#RUN chmod +x ./install_docker.sh && sh ./install_docker.sh
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt install -y git python3-pip libxml-simple-perl libncursesw5 && \
    git clone https://github.com/CAMI-challenge/CAMISIM.git && \
    pip3 install numpy ete3 biom-format biopython matplotlib joblib scikit-learn 
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
ENV PATH="/CAMISIM/:${PATH}"
```

This yields :

```
sudo docker run camisim:latest metagenomesimulation.py --help
python3: can't open file 'metagenomesimulation.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Adding that script as an `ENTRYPOINT` after `python3` allows me to use it with 2 drawbacks: I cannot use another script (I could build a second docker image but that would be a bad solution), and it outputs:

```
ERROR: 0
usage: python metagenomesimulation.py configuration_file_path

    #######################################
    #    MetagenomeSimulationPipeline     #
    #######################################

    Pipeline for the simulation of a metagenome

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -silent, --silent     Hide unimportant Progress Messages.
  -debug, --debug_mode  more information, also temporary data will not be deleted
  -log LOGFILE, --logfile LOGFILE
                        output will also be written to this log file

optional config arguments:
  -seed SEED            seed for random number generators
  -s {0,1,2}, --phase {0,1,2}
                        available options: 0,1,2. Default: 0
                        0 -> Full run,
                        1 -> Only Comunity creation,
                        2 -> Only Readsimulator
  -id DATA_SET_ID, --data_set_id DATA_SET_ID
                        id of the dataset, part of prefix of read/contig sequence ids
  -p MAX_PROCESSORS, --max_processors MAX_PROCESSORS
                        number of available processors

required:
  config_file           path to the configuration file
```

You can see there is an error that should'nt be there, it actually does not use the `help` flag. The original Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y python3 python3-pip perl libncursesw5
RUN perl -MCPAN -e 'install XML::Simple'
ADD requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN cat requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 pip install
ADD *.py /usr/local/bin/
ADD scripts /usr/local/bin/scripts
ADD tools /usr/local/bin/tools
ADD defaults /usr/local/bin/defaults
WORKDIR /usr/local/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]
```

It works but shows the error as above, so not so much. Said error is not present when using the tool outside of docker. Last time I made a Docker image I just pulled the git repo and added the main `.sh` script as an `ENTRYPOINT` and everything worked despite being more complex (see https://github.com/Louis-MG/Metadbgwas).

Why would I need `ADD` and moving everything ? I added the git folder to the path, why can't I find the scripts ? How is it different from the Metadbgwas image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end very little was recquired and the original `Dockerfile` was correct, the same error is displayed anyway, that is due to the script itself.
What was missing was a link to the interpreter, so I could remove the `ENTRYPOINT` and actually interpret the script instead of having `python` look for it in its own path. The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
USER root

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

RUN apt-get update && \
        apt install -y git python3-pip libxml-simple-perl libncursesw5 && \
        git clone https://github.com/CAMI-challenge/CAMISIM.git && \
        pip3 install numpy ete3 biom-format biopython matplotlib joblib scikit-learn
ENV PATH="/CAMISIM:${PATH}"
```

Trying `WORKDIR` as suggested instead of the `PATH` yielded an error.

Answer (score 0):

In your first setup, you start in the image root directory `/` and run `git clone` to check out the repository into `/CAMISIM`.  You never change the current directory, though, so when you try to run `python3 metagenomesimulation.py --help` it's looking in `/` and not `/CAMISIM`, hence the "not found" error.

You can fix this just by changing the current directory.  At any point after you check out the repository, run

```bash
WORKDIR /CAMISIM
```

You should also delete the `ENTRYPOINT` line.  For each of the scripts you could run as a top-level entry point, check two things:

1. Is it executable; if you `ls -l metagenomesimulation.py` are there `x` in the permission listing?  If not, on the host system, run `chmod +x metagenomesimulation.py` and commit to source control.  (Or you could `RUN chmod ...` in the Dockerfile if you really can't change the repository.)
2. Does it have a "shebang" line?  The very first line of the script should be

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   ```

If both of these things are true, then you can just run `./metagenomesimulation.py` without explicitly saying `python3`; since you add the directory to `$PATH` as well, you can probably run it without specifying the `./...` file location.

(Probably deleting the `ENTRYPOINT` line on its own is enough, given that `ENV PATH` setting, but your script still might be confused by starting up in the wrong directory.)

The long "help" output just suggests to me that the script is expecting a configuration file name as a parameter and you haven't provided it, or else you've repeated the script name in both the entrypoint and command parts of the container command string.

Comment: The `ENTRYPOINT` had to be removed in favor of `RUN ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python` . Then my Dockerfile worked ! Wihtout this your solution was not working either. Now just calling the script goes to the right interpreter instead of looking for a file/dir _in its own executable path_. Thanks for the suggestion of 'chmod', good idea, even if not the solution this time ! Will post the final Dockerfile.